# Under what circumstances will all tasks in a stage execute in same executor

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark application. It will join some table many times and write the result to HDFS.

My submit script:

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 14G \
--driver-cores 6 \
--executor-memory 14G \
--executor-cores 4 \
--num-executors 50 \
--conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=31457280 \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=200 \
--class my.main.class\
my.jar
```

**Problem:**
In Spark WebUI,I fond individual stages are executed in the same exector:
[image: all executor]
Why 200 tasks in a stage be executed in same executor pc-xxxx269?
[image]

Comment: Which source are you reading from?

Comment: All tables reading from hdfs

Comment: Are you running Spark on top of your HDFS cluster?

Comment: Thnaks @yuval . Yes, `--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster` is specify Spark to run on the yarn cluster

Comment: Is your data properly replicated across HDFS data nodes such that you can read different files from different executors?

Comment: In hdfs-site.xml `dfs.replication=3`, But there are 500 macthines in the cluster, It's difficult to read file in local mode

Comment: I'm facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it could happen in two ways 
 1 . There is no proper partition is being applied
 2 . In case if you are using the Hash partitioned , the all the Keys hash value are close enough

Comment: thanks @Guda I'm using Hash partitioned. but if keys hash value are close enough,it should be skew.just like:task1 extcute 1G data and task2-200 execute nothing.